# Extjs 4 FiltersFeature vs stateful grid

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs4, stateful

I have a grid with some columns with filters.
columns defination:

```
columns:[{
                text: "Number",
                dataIndex: 'clientreference',
                width: 200,
                filter: true,
                sortable: true
            },
```

here is filter feature defination

```
features: [{
                ftype: 'filters',
                encode: true,
                local: false
            }],
```

The problem is: When i'm trying to save state of grid, filters are not working: When I adding this code to a grid:

```
stateful: true,
stateId: 'documentsGrid',
```

I refresh the page and all works fine, because i dont have state in my cookies.
But when I refresh the page second time - state loads from cookies and filters are not working.
If i remove stateful: true and refresh page, filters are working fine.
Any suggestions?
Also I noticed, that all examples in extjs site are only with filters or with stateful grid, but there is no one example with both.

UPDATED:
The most useful way was making my own method for saving state of elements I need and to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are specifying features in grid.But you can specify filters in store directly.So try to define filters in store and stateful in grid config options.Hope you may get the solution to come out from this.

Comment: How can I define filters in store with same functionality?

Comment: Once check the URL: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-property-filters

Comment: It cant be useful, because I need manually create  a textfield for each column in my grid, I need manually set every filter from fields to store.filters and what about filter like filter:{type:'date'}? there are 3 fields with calendars. So, it is very hard to use different filters on many columns of data.